# How to generate a dynamic form using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, form-generator

I need to generate an entire html form dynamically based on the Ajax response from server. In response there will be information like input type , input labels, validations if any etc.

The form at most will always have ten fields.

Is there any jQuery/ javascript tool/plugin to generate the form?

Thanks.

Comment: It's very simple why don't you try yourself

Comment: @AmGates. Hi I know its simple but I just wanted to know if there is any tools or plugins available which will speed-en up the development. I mean why to reinvent the wheel again ;-)

Comment: It will take an iterator, assuming the Ajax response has everything you need in it. There's no reasonable way to make this faster with a plugin, and the iterator *is* the tool! I'm with AmGates; give it a go!

Comment: @Greg Pettit . Okay. Let me try it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Formation](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Formation)

From their example:

```
    value = {"key":"value"} "key" will be the value attribute and "value" will be the shown value of the element. If the array is constructed like {"value",value","value"} (without keys) then the value attribute of the input will be an auto-incremented number starting from 0.
options = {} See options table below.

$.fn.formation(options); [Create a form]
$.formation.addInput(options); [Append an input]
$.formation.addSelect(values,options); [Append a select]
$.formation.addTextarea(options); [Append a textarea]
$.formation.addCheckboxes(values,options); [Append an unordered list of checkboxes]
$.formation.addRadios(values,options); [Append an unordered list of radio buttons]
$.formation.addCaptcha(options); [Adds a captcha question to your form]
$.formation.addButton(options); [Append a button]
$.formation.setErrorMessages(options); [Set custom error messages for validation]
```

However, this is all stuff you can easily do with Jquery, and it is a good learning experience so I recommend trying it yourself.